problema para relacionar una entiddad en msql worbeack
hola   comunidad  de   devs code..!!  tengo  un  problemilla  para  intentar  relacionar  una  tabla  ya que  en   la  tabla  que  quiero relacionar con las  demás intento  agregar 3  columnas  claves  para  trae  los registro  requeridos  de  la demas.!  me  gustaria  saber  como  lo  puedo  resolver  o  cuales  es  la  forma  correcta  de  relacionarlas una muestra..>>  la  columas  seria  ultima  visita medica, ultima  visita atencion_general,  ultima visita urgencias;

aqui  la  primera  imagen  de  la  entidades  que  intento  relacionar   con la  otra  que  seria:


Partes de un diseño muy mejorable: ¿Cómo es que has hecho una tabla para cada unidad y no has hecho una tabla unidades? Se ve claramente que comparten un montón de campos que deberían estar en una única tabla, lo que te obliga a incluir campos id en HISTORIA_CLINICA que te complican la consulta que quieres hacer. ¿Esto ya está en producción o estamos a tiempo de arreglarlo?

Por otra parte, no te quedes con las últimas visitas y citas, regístralas todas y obtén la última como un campo calculado, que algo te aportarán.

GRACIAS  GRAN  AMIGO..!!  ME  HICISTE  DE  MUCHA  AYUDA  PARA SOLUCIONAR  ESTE  PROBLEMA  EN MI  ESTUDIO  EN LA  UNIVERSIDAD

gracias  amigo pro  ayudarme  me  sirvió  mucho  tu  consejo  en  este  trabajo  en la  universidad
